# Ubuntu desktop started freezing suddenly after working fine for months

Tags: unity, nvidia, graphics

I installed Ubuntu a couple of months ago. My desktop was working perfectly until yesterday, when I restarted the system and my desktop froze showing a weird background image.

[image]

I can't right click on the desktop and desktop is totally hung, but everything else is working.

And sometimes unity gets completely hung and I need to restart the system.

- Ubuntu 17.04
- I have three monitors (2K-primary, FullHD, HD)
- lspci | grep VGA = VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM206 [GeForce GTX 950] (rev a1)
- NVIDIA 375.66 (nvidia-375)

I tried reinstalling nvidia driver but it didn't help.

Comment: Try `nvidia-381` from `ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`

Comment: Installed nvidia-381 , Not fixed